# How can I automate the creation of Polaroid-like images in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, batch, automation, special-effects

I would to create a canvas with dozens, perhaps close to 100, polaroid-like photographs strewn about it. 
I have the image files in one folder. In order to create the canvas, I'd have to import each photo and place it on a Polaroid card layout, save and reimport the Polaroid card into the large canvas. This might take a while.

Is there any way I can automate all, or even part of this process?

Comment: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html

Comment: No use to you - but may be of interest to people who look at this question in future - Picasa (from Google) has a facility to produce collages of this type automatically.  See http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/45594/what-software-can-make-collages-which-look-like-multiple-polaroids-on-a-wall

Answer (score 2):

Photoshop scripts are the best way to achieve this I feel. Google "Photoshop scripts polaroid"....here's one I found that might just be what you're looking for - [Polaroid Generator](http://rawimage.deviantart.com/art/Polaroid-GENERATOR-V2-118854065)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Mac, take a look at [Automator](http://www.automator.us/leopard/index.html) to help you automate these repetitive tasks. [Photoshop Automator Actions](http://www.robotphotoshop.com/?page_id=8) is a set of actions that look promising (I haven't tried them) for creating the kind of workflow you're talking about.