# What software can make collages which look like multiple Polaroids on a wall?

Tags: software, presentation, collage

Does a specific software exists which could simplify the process of making collective images such as these?

[image]
[image]

... preferably with some options (like "pins", some visual effects on the "polaroids" etc). Currently I'm doing it manually, but it is a lot of work.

Not sure if this is exactly on topic here, or just bordering, but it seems it could be a relatively often demand of customers.

Comment: Duplicate?  http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10424/recommendations-for-photo-montage-collage-software

Comment: @D.Lambert I've coincidentally suggested the same answer - which makes me think it's probably a duplicate.

Comment: I suppose this question does specifically mention Polaroids - which the other question and answers make no mention of - and which Picasa has (though they avoid mentioning Polaroid by name).

Answer (score 3):

I use Picasa it is a great option. But let us know what Operating System are you using. For Mac there is some apps like [CollageIt](http://www.collageitfree.com/) and [Posterino](http://zykloid.com/posterino) who does a great job, there are not free but I'll help a lot in the process. Is more easier to put a *pin deco* in Photoshop than do the whole workflow. There also a few options in mobile apps,  since Im new I can post more links, but Diptic is one of my favorites. Again, it hels a lot in the process maybe does not all the job but *agilize* the process.

Answer (score 2):

Picasa 3.0 (free from [Google](http://picasa.google.co.uk/)) has a picture collage function which allows you to create merged images like the examples in your question.  It includes a picture border option that allows a "polaroid" style and allows you to place (and rotate) images by hand.

Comment: I don't see an option for "pins" - so you'd have to add these in a later stage in your workflow using your favourite image editor (and a suitable image of a "pin" to clone).

Answer (score 1):

[TurboCollage](http://www.turbocollage.com), available for both Mac and Windows PC, can [make collages that look like multiple spread out polaroids.](http://www.turbocollage.com/howto-make-picture-pile-scrapbook.html#instant-photo-collage)

Here's a sample screenshot of designing such a photo using TurboCollage:

[image: design photo]

(disclosure: I work for the company that makes TurboCollage)

Answer (score 0):

TurboCollage, Picture Collage Maker and CollageFactory Pro are all great Mac tools for creating collages with a polaroid look/feel.

CollageFactory Pro is also available as a Windows application, though I have not had any experience with that version.